# Gdx-tools.jar in LibGDX is giving Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 error

Tags: android

I am working on developing a game in libgdx.Everything is going well until I got this error.I was working on implementing animations in android game using libgdx and for the related I was following this tutorial:
   http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-tutorial-part-2-animation/

I need to use TexturePacker2 class in gdx-tools.jar for packing a set of images in a larger image to make my game fast(It generates .pack file in assets folder).So I include gdx-tools.jar in libs folder of my project.When i run it,DVM is giving the following error at compile time:

Description of error:

```
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.Native$1) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.Native$2) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.Native$3) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.Native$4) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.Native$5) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.Native$6) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.Native$7) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary$1) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary$2) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.Structure$1) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.Structure$2) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions$1) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions$2) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.win32.W32APITypeMapper$1) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class  (com.sun.jna.win32.W32APITypeMapper$2) that doesn't come with an  associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a  compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended  solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler  and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring  this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly  indicate that it is *not* an inner class.  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx   trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":    Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)  when not building a core library.    This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file  in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as  Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a  core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's  going on.    However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core  namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,  from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most  assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the  compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.  It is also often of questionable legality.    If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only  appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine  distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use  the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.    If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact  building an application, then be forewarned that your application  will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be  prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your  application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating  system. You will be to blame for this problem.    If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a  core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to  repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into  your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in  conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help  you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then  that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately  lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.    
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Dx 1 error; aborting  
[2014-04-10 18:44:48 - Game] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

I have gone through each and every stackoverflow post regarding this error bu nothing seems to help me.Help from anyone is highly appriciated :)

Comment: There is no one who can answer it??

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. gdx-tools.jar apparently is meant only for desktop application, not Android ...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately according to their github gdx-tools is only supported on desktop. We all hope they will add android support soon.

Here's [a link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#tools-gradle)!

http://imgur.com/3wXNjau